# I can't understand what cause Unable to start activity java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, exception, android-activity, null, crash

I made some changes to my app and now I'm getting this error that seems to be related to a class (**ViewUser**) that i do not changed.

I tried to undo some changes that i made in other classes but i cannot figure out what could cause this error.
I double checked somethings according to this answer but i do not solved.

Here is the LogCat:

```
02-21 11:46:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(22002): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 11:46:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(22002): Process: com.myapp, PID: 22002
02-21 11:46:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(22002): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.ViewUser}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 11:46:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(22002):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2212)
02-21 11:46:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(22002):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
02-21 11:46:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(22002):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
02-21 11:46:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(22002):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
02-21 11:46:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(22002):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-21 11:46:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(22002):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-21 11:46:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(22002):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
02-21 11:46:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(22002):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 11:46:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(22002):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-21 11:46:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(22002):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
02-21 11:46:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(22002):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
02-21 11:46:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(22002):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-21 11:46:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(22002): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 11:46:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(22002):    at com.myapp.ViewUser.onCreate(ViewUser.java:33)
02-21 11:46:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(22002):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-21 11:46:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(22002):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-21 11:46:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(22002):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
02-21 11:46:43.133: E/AndroidRuntime(22002):    ... 11 more
```

Please tell me if i have to show you some files, thank you in advance!

Comment: show us your activity and xml code.

You can restore the changes from local history as well in eclipse.

Comment: Show `ViewUser `class `onCreate` method code

Comment: Here is ViewUser class, thank you: http://pastebin.com/L8UTuSRH

Comment: what is at line 33 in ViewUser.java ?

Comment: On line 33 there is this: `mPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);`
Anyway i do not make any changes on this file... it is for this that i can't figure out the real cause of this error.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted Eclipse and now it works! O_o